# How do I link a module (not project) in android studio to firebase? how is it different from linking app to firebase?

Tags: java, android, module

I built a project and linked it to firebase and it works well, but I was not able to convert it into a module.
So, I created a new project and added a new module to it. Now, I wish to link this module to firebase just like it would've been if I was able to convert my previously created project to a module and import it to my new project.

A module that is linked to firebase from which I can receive and send data. 
I'm basically trying to build a registration form (module) that can be used in any project.

Answer (score 0):

got in contact with firebase support staff and they explained to me why it's not possible. 
So, not possible.